# Jmeter 16 digit card number is not passing through csv file

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing rest API with Csv data config using 16 digit card numbers,but while execution started **cardNo** displaying as null in request but I've mention 16 digit card numbers to test.

Why is it not accepting 16 digit card numbers to pass in request using CSV Data Set config?

Card File:

```
cardno,scode,tNo,txnNo,txn_Date,Amount
1061557318991070,1234,30,40001,15-05-2018,200.60
```

POST data:

```
{
   "cardNo": "null",
    "mobileNo":null,
   "sCode": 1234,
   "tNo": "30",
   "MemoNo": 40001,
   "MemoDate": "15-05-2018",
   "Amount":"200.60"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's limitation on CSV values is 2+ gigabytes, the fact you're getting "null" most probably indicates wrong [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup.

Given:

1. Your CSV file
2. The following CSV Data Set Config setup:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
3. I'm able to see all the values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination:

   [image: JMeter Variable from CSV]

Comment: Your Images are not displaying showing Page not found error